# Wrap two lines of text together on responsive design

Tags: html, css

how can i achieve this for a responsive design?

```
C       Cmaj7      F      
Imagine there's no heaven 

C         Cmaj7  F      
It's easy if you try
```

```
C       Cmaj7            
Imagine there's 
   F
no heaven 

C         Cmaj7        
It's easy if 
    F
you try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping every word in an element, in this case a `span`, we can force the lines to have spacing when they start to wrap.

The `::before` pseudo element can be used to set the chord at any word by using `content: attr(data-chord);` and positioning it above that word - effectively taking it out of the normal DOM positioning.

Hope that helps.

```css
p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

p span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 1.4em;
}


p span[data-chord] {
  position: relative;
}

p span[data-chord]::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.4em;
  content: attr(data-chord);
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span data-chord="C">Imagine</span>
  <span data-chord="Cmaj7">there's</span>
  <span>no</span>
  <span data-chord="F">heaven</span>
</p>

<p>
  <span data-chord="C">It's</span>
  <span>easy</span>
  <span data-chord="Cmaj7">if</span>
  <span>you</span>
  <span data-chord="F">try</span>
</p>
```

Comment: That's a really cool solution, but you should explain how it works.

Comment: Updated with an explanation, let me know if that makes sense and feel free to upvote if it works well :)